# Responsive height of react-native-modal according to number of elements in it

Tags: react-native

i am trying to create a modal  in react native application, and there is a button or touchable opacity on a screen which toggles the modal, i am trying to populate a list of items on modal by the use of mapping. But it is not working as expected because elements i create are hidden behind other elements.

I have tried using Modal from react native but i was unable to set custom size of the modal as i needed some portion of it to be transparent. That is why i moved to react-native-modal library but i am facing above mentioned error in that.

```
<Modal isVisible={this.state.modalVisible} >
                    <View style={{backgroundColor:'white', alignItems:'center', borderRadius:5}}>
                        <Image source={require('../../assets/Group3Copy.png')} style={{marginTop:responsiveFontSize, marginBottom:responsiveFontSize-2}}/>
                        <Text style={{color:'#92c848', alignSelf:'center', fontWeight:'bold', fontSize:responsiveFontSize+10}}>Well Done!</Text>
                        <Text style={{color:blueColor, fontWeight:'bold'}}>{this.state.plantCount} plants have been planted</Text>
                        <Text style={{color:blueColor, fontWeight:'bold'}}> {this.state.plantCount} پودے لگاۓ گۓ ہيں </Text>


                        {/* Mapping=========================================== */}

                        <View style={AppStyles.mainNoRow}>
                        <View style={AppStyles.colNoIco}>
                            <Image source={require('../../assets/plant.png')}/>
                        </View>
                        <View style={AppStyles.colOrderNoDetail}>
                            <Text style={{color:"#006f91", alignSelf:'flex-start', fontWeight:'bold',marginTop:10}}>Plant</Text>
                            <Text style={{color:"#747474", alignSelf:'flex-start', fontWeight:'bold',}}>Id</Text>
                        </View>

                        <View style={AppStyles.colOrderPickupYesDetail}>
                            <Text style={{color:greenColor ,fontWeight:'bold',}}>1 Jan 19</Text>
                            <Image source={require('../../assets/address.png')}/>
                        </View>
                    </View>



                       <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._toggleModal}
                        style={{
                        width: "90%",
                        height: 60,
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        alignSelf: "center",
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        borderRadius: 8,
                        borderColor: blueColor,
                        shadowColor: blueColor,
                        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
                        shadowOpacity: 0.9,
                        shadowRadius: 1,
                        backgroundColor: blueColor,
                        marginBottom:responsiveFontSize}} >
                        <Text style={AppStyles.textStylePlant}>OK</Text>

                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                </Modal>
```

I expect it's height to be set according to the number of elements mapped on it. and adjust it automatically if that is possible.
But right now elements are overlapping like shown here in this picture. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAZlq.png 
Elements are hidden behind 'OK' button.

Answer (score 0):

Adding marginBottom to the styling of main row seems to resolve the issue. And it also resize the height of modal accordingly.